# replacing special characters without using escape sequence in unix file

Tags: unix, shell-script, solaris

I am trying to replace a string with special characters like " &,*,@" etc.
This should be done without using escape sequence. I am using sed but it is not working without escape sequence. I am in a situation to pass the new string dynamically. Kindly suggest on this.

sed -e 's/567890/csaf&dsac/g' /test.txt > output.txt.

My Output: csaf567890dsac

Expected Output:csaf&dsac

Thank You,
Karthick

Comment: Why should it work without escaping?

Comment: use  `perl -pe 's/567890/csaf&dsac/g' /test.txt > output.txt`